# Detecting drag in fyne

Tags: go, fyne

How can I detect a drag event in a widget? I've tried this:

```golang
    type drawRect struct {
        widget.Card
    }

    func (e *drawRect) Dragged(d *fyne.DragEvent) {
        fmt.Println("A")
    }
```

but it is not called when I drag over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dragging an item you need to implement the whole Draggable interface (you missed `DragEnd`) https://developer.fyne.io/api/v2.0/draggable.html.

However what you describe may be a drop event (part of the OS drag and drop lifecycle) which is not yet supported. The draggable behaviour is for the user feature of dragging an object inside your UI.